# Images keep running off the page

Tags: graphics, floats

I am really having trouble with LaTeX. I am a complete noob only just started using it and took to it rather well. 
However I am having a lot of trouble with the `figure` environment.

I am using the Royal Astronomical Astronomy LaTeX Template. The problems I am having is:

1. When I want to put `figure` in my results section and in the PDF it they just go somewhere random in the document.
2. I have a lot of figures and they need to fit the column width, which they do perfectly however There are so many that they just flow off the end of the page and I don't know how to move them to the next column instead (I will attach pics. I have tried using the [r] and other syntax such as this but all they do is print a letter "r" next to the plot.

[image: packages used]
[image: plots running off the page]

The code used to import the images is

```
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{E_L_FIR}
\caption{CAPTION}
\label{Figure 1}
```

Please help
Thanks!

Silas Mawdsley

Comment: You have not shown enough code for anyone to guess why the figures are running off the page.  Did you put all the images into a single figure?

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Also try and post your full examples in the text not as images. Furthermore you're asking two questions at once, which is frowned upon.

Comment: Hi Thanks, just sorted it by splitting it up into different images. and didnt realise that sorry dude! thanks guys!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because OP has solved the question by himself, as stated in the comments.